# execute query in zend returns null

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I run this query directly in phpmyadmin , it perfectly returns result !!
but when I run this query in my php script , it returns **NULL**

this is my db class:

```
class Product extends Places_Db_Table_Row_Observable  {
    protected $_name = 'product';
    PUBLIC function getMaxSubcatProduct()
    {


        $query = $this->getAdapter()->query("select  max( c ) AS maxcount,id from ( select COUNT(*) as c 
                    ,product_sub_category_id as id  from product group by product_sub_category_id ) as max ");
        $res = $query->fetchAll();
        return $res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello please write the "public" in lower case this is suggestion and i am try to solve your problem

Comment: no thing changed!! it returns null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was my fault! I showed the result in my script like this :

```
echo $this->masterMenu["id"];
```

but correct way is:

```
foreach ($this->masterMenu as $key => $value)
                    {
                        $masterMenu =    $value['id'];
                    }
```